# Exclude objects in Symfony dropdown form type

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form type that shows a dropdown with objects from my `ArticleCategory` entity. It's all working, however, I want to exclude some of the objects - the ones that I have set to `state` = `false`. In the dropdown I only want objects with their state set to `true`. How can I make that happen? Here is how my code looks like:

```
->add('category', null, [
  'required' => true,
  'label' => 'Category',
  'choice_label' => 'title',
  'placeholder' => 'Choose category',
  'class' => ArticleCategory::class,
  'autocomplete' => true,
])
```

Comment: Have two different fields instead: unmapped one for rendering purposes and a bound field as the proper one. You can switch values using a model transformer. Also easily doable with a single, custom form type as well (that would have two fields too.)

Comment: Take a look at the `choice_filter` option:  https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-filter You can probably do something like `'choice_filter' => 'state',` as in their second example.